# Database insertion is taking zero seconds to insert

Tags: java, database, multithreading

I am trying to measure the performance of `Database Insert`. So for that I have written a `StopWatch` class which will reset the counter before `executeUpdate` method and calculate the time after `executeUpdate` method is done.

And I am trying to see how much time each thread is taking, so I am keeping those numbers in a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Below is my main class-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int noOfThreads = 4;
        final int noOfTasks = 100;

        final AtomicInteger id = new AtomicInteger(1);

        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noOfThreads);

        for (int i = 0; i < noOfTasks * noOfThreads; i++) {
            service.submit(new Task(id));
        }
        while (!service.isTerminated()) {

        }

           //printing the histogram
          System.out.println(Task.histogram);

    }
```

Below is the class that implements Runnable in which I am trying to measure each thread performance in inserting to database meaning how much time each thread is taking to insert to database-

```
class Task implements Runnable {

    private final AtomicInteger id;
    private StopWatch totalExecTimer = new StopWatch(Task.class.getSimpleName() + ".totalExec");
    public static ConcurrentHashMap<Long, AtomicLong> histogram = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, AtomicLong>();

    public Task(AtomicInteger id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        dbConnection = getDBConnection();

        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(Constants.INSERT_ORACLE_SQL);

        //other preparedStatement

        totalExecTimer.resetLap();

        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        totalExecTimer.accumulateLap();

        final AtomicLong before = histogram.putIfAbsent(totalExecTimer.getCumulativeTime() / 1000, new AtomicLong(1L));
        if (before != null) {
            before.incrementAndGet();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the `StopWatch class`

```
/**
 * A simple stop watch.
 */
protected static class StopWatch {
    private final String name;
    private long lapStart;
    private long cumulativeTime;

    public StopWatch(String _name) {
        name = _name;
    }

    /**
     * Resets lap start time.
     */
    public void resetLap() {
        lapStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    /**
     * Accumulates the lap time and return the current lap time.
     * 
     * @return the current lap time.
     */
    public long accumulateLap() {
        long lapTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - lapStart;
        cumulativeTime += lapTime;
        return lapTime;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current cumulative lap time.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public long getCumulativeTime() {
        return cumulativeTime;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(name);
        sb.append("=");
        sb.append((cumulativeTime / 1000));
        sb.append("s");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

After running the above program, I can see 400 rows got inserted. And when it is printing the histogram, I am only seeing like this-

```
{0=400}
```

which means 400 calls came back in 0 seconds? It's not possible for sure.

**I am just trying to see how much time each thread is taking to insert the record and then store those numbers in a `Map` and print that map from the main thread.**

I think the problem I am assuming it's happening because of thread safety here and that is the reason whenever it is doing `resetlap` zero is getting set to Map I guess.

If yes how can I avoid this problem? And also it is required to pass `histogram map` from the main thread to constructor of Task? As I need to print that Map after all the threads are finished to see what numbers are there.

**Update:-**
If I remove `divide by 1000` thing to store the number as milliseconds then I am able to see some numbers apart from `zero`. So that looks good.

But One thing more I found out is that numbers are not consistent, If I sum up each threads time, I will get some number for that. And I also I am printing how much time in which whole program is finishing as well. SO I compare these two numbers they are different by big margin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid concurrency issues with your stopwatch you're probably better off creating a new one as a local variable within the `run` method of your `Runnable`.  That way each thread has it's own stopwatch.

As for the timing you're seeing, I would absolutely hope that a simple record insert would happen in well under a second.  Seeing 400 inserts that all happen in less than a second each doesn't surprise me at all.  You may get better results by using the millisecond value from your stopwatch as your HashMap key.

**Update**

For the stopwatch concurrency problem I'm suggesting something like this:

```
class Task implements Runnable {

    private final AtomicInteger id;
    // Remove the stopwatch from here
    //private StopWatch totalExecTimer = new StopWatch(Task.class.getSimpleName() + ".totalExec");
    public static ConcurrentHashMap<Long, AtomicLong> histogram = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, AtomicLong>();

    public Task(AtomicInteger id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        // And add it here
        StopWatch totalExecTimer = new StopWatch(Task.class.getSimpleName() + ".totalExec");

        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
```

In this way each thread, indeed each Task, gets its own copy, and you don't have to worry about concurrency.  Making the StopWatch thread-safe as-is is probably more trouble than it's worth.

**Update 2**

Having said that then the approach you mentioned in your comment would probably give better results, as there's less overhead in the timing mechanism.

To answer your question about the difference in cumulative thread time and the toal running time of the program I would glibbly say, "What did you expect?".

There are two issues here.  One is that you're not measuring the total running time of each thread, just the bit where you're doing the DB insert.

The other is that measuring the running time of the whole application does not take into account any overlap in the execution times of the threads.  Even if you were measuring the total time of each task, and assuming you're running on a multi-core machine, I would expect the cumulative time to be more than the elapse time of program execution.  That's the benefit of parallel programming.

Comment: I see. So you are saying I should use something like this `long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();` before `executeUpdate` method and then this line `long difference = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time);`. But still I am trying to make that StopWatch to work if there are any concurrency issues in that.

Comment: And Update 2 answers your question about total running time

Comment: Yes there are concurrency issues on the timer.  There's nothing to stop once thread from resetting the timer in the middle of a time-span that another thread is trying to measure.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your suggestion. I implemented most of them. And in regards to your previous comment, how can I fix that concurrency issues on the timer? Any thoughts?

Comment: Like I said, I think it's more trouble than it's worth.  You can't use locks because that would really screw up your results.  You could probably use a semaphore of some kind to mark the timer "in use" so only one thread can use it at a time, but then you lose any possible benefit of your multithreading.

Comment: The other possibility would be to use a ConcurrentHashMap, with the thread id as the key, to store the timer values.  This would allow each thread to use the one timer independently.  But any blocking that occurs inside the ConcurrentHashMap would, again, screw up your results.

Comment: Make sense to me. So you are saying, I should just do the way I suggested in one of my first comments right? Which can solve the problem of this concurrency issue right?

Comment: That's the way I'd go, yes.

Answer (score 1):

As an additional note, System.currentTimeMillis() is pseudo time and has a level of innacuracy.  Using System.nanoTime() is a more accurate approach

```
long start = System.nanoTime();

long end = System.nanoTime();

long timeInSeconds = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.convert(end-start, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a number of reasons, currentTimeMillis is apt to not "refresh" its value on every call.  You should use nanoTime for high-resolution measurements.

And your code is throwing away fractions of a second.  Your toString method should use `sb.append((cumulativeTime / 1000.0));` so that you get fractional seconds.

But the overhead of your timing mechanism is substantial, and if you ever do measure something a big chunk of the time will just be the timing overhead.  It's much better to measure a number of operations rather than just one.

Comment: Yeah. I will be doing that for sure by running for a longer period of time. But before that I needed to make sure it is working fine or not because there can be thread safety issue here as well. So just wanted to confirm that whether the numbers I am getting is right or not

Comment: Other thing I have noticed is, if I sum up all the threads time and compare with total execution of my program, they both are different by long margin. So I believe there are some thread safety issue here?